# Pandas - Groupby multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to group by multiple columns, and aggregate them so that they become a list after grouping.

Currently, the `DataFrame` looks like this:

[image]

I've tried to use this:

```
grouped = DataFrame.groupby(['jobname', 'block'], axis=0)
DataFrame= grouped.aggregate(lambda x: list(x))
```

However, when I apply this in IPython, it gives me this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-221-97113b757fa1> in <module>()
----> 1 cassandraFrame_2 = grouped.aggregate(lambda x: list(x))
      2 cassandraFrame_2

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby.pyc in aggregate(self, arg, *args, **kwargs)
   2867 
   2868             if self.grouper.nkeys > 1:
-> 2869                 return self._python_agg_general(arg, *args, **kwargs)
   2870             else:
   2871 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby.pyc in _python_agg_general(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
   1166         for name, obj in self._iterate_slices():
   1167             try:
-> 1168                 result, counts = self.grouper.agg_series(obj, f)
   1169                 output[name] = self._try_cast(result, obj)
   1170             except TypeError:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby.pyc in agg_series(self, obj, func)
   1633             return self._aggregate_series_fast(obj, func)
   1634         except Exception:
-> 1635             return self._aggregate_series_pure_python(obj, func)
   1636 
   1637     def _aggregate_series_fast(self, obj, func):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby.pyc in _aggregate_series_pure_python(self, obj, func)
   1667                 if (isinstance(res, (Series, Index, np.ndarray)) or
   1668                         isinstance(res, list)):
-> 1669                     raise ValueError('Function does not reduce')
   1670                 result = np.empty(ngroups, dtype='O')
   1671 

ValueError: Function does not reduce
```

Ultimately, I want to group the same jobname, and block together, but the data is a list of tuples, right now it is a 3 item tuple.

For Example:

```
jobname       block         data
Complete-Test Simple_buff   (tuple_1)
Complete-Test Simple_buff   (tuple_2)
```

Aggregate:

```
jobname       block         data
Complete-Test Simple_buff   [(tuple_1),(tuple_2)]
```

I could group by `jobname`, however, this aggregates the `block` together, but I want to keep the `blocks` seperate.

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the result that you want to obtain? The error message says that you need to give a reducing function to `aggregate`, i.e. returning a scalar for each group (and not a list or array)

Comment: @joris, I've updated my question for what I wanted to obtain. Basically if jobname and block are the same, then combine two tuples together to form a list of two tuples. Sometimes there are only 1 tuple, and sometimes 2 or more tuples to be combined.

Comment: The traceback suggests that the aggregating function can't return a list, but a tuple would work.

Comment: Tried tuple, and it works... Odd that list wouldn't work. Would you mind writing up an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like there is an explicit check that the value returned by the aggregating function is not a `Series`, `Index`, `np.ndarray`, or a `list`.

So, the following should work:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['jobname', 'block'])
aggregated = grouped.aggregate(lambda x: tuple(x))
```